# Get the number of arguments in a function python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to verify if the client gave the right amount of arguments to the server.

I have this function:

```
def invite_player(addr, active_users):
```

how can I verify the number of arguments of this function?

Comment: Your code will raise a `TypeError` if there are not exactly 2 arguments.

Comment: Moreover, functions are ordinarily called from Python code within the same program. What are you calling "client" and "server"? If you are exposing the function with a framework that allows  remote procedure calls, each such framework will have a different way of introspecting the function signatures. You have to give more information on that, if it is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the argument count of a function and then compare it.

I assume that your function don't takes any keyword argument.

```py
>>> def invite_player(addr, active_users):
    ...


>>> invite_player.__code__.co_argcount
2
```

The better way would be using builtin [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module:

```py
>>> import inspect
>>> def invite_player(addr, active_users):
    ...


>>> inspect.getfullargspec(invite_player)
FullArgSpec(args=['addr', 'active_users'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(invite_player)[0]
['addr', 'active_users']
>>> len(inspect.getfullargspec(invite_player)[0])
2
```

Also a `TypeError` would raise if you don't pass right amount of arguments to the function, but this is not the only thing that raises `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the function can only be called with 2 arguments. If not, a TypeError will be raised.